# Cannot borrow `x` as mutable more than once at a time?

Tags: rust, lifetime

Logically this code is correct, However rust doesn't  understand the context. Trying to reading some byte from cursor with very short 'lifetime of exclusive reference.

Why this code does not compile? [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=29f16de4f226057b200e1501da92fef2)

```rust
struct Cursor {
    offset: usize,
    data: [u8; 4],
}
impl Cursor {
    fn read_slice(&mut self, n: usize) -> &[u8] {
        let data = &self.data[self.offset..self.offset + n];
        self.offset += n;
        data
    }
}
struct FooBar<'a> {
    foo: &'a [u8],
    bar: &'a [u8],
}

fn read_foobar_from<'a>(cursor: &'a mut Cursor) -> FooBar<'a> {
    FooBar {
        foo: cursor.read_slice(2),
        bar: cursor.read_slice(2),
    }
}
```

Error:

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `*cursor` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src/main.rs:22:14
   |
19 |   fn read_foobar_from<'a>(cursor: &'a mut Cursor) -> FooBar<'a> {
   |                       -- lifetime `'a` defined here
20 | /     FooBar {
21 | |         foo: cursor.read_slice(2),
   | |              -------------------- first mutable borrow occurs here
22 | |         bar: cursor.read_slice(2),
   | |              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ second mutable borrow occurs here
23 | |     }
   | |_____- returning this value requires that `*cursor` is borrowed for `'a`
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot borrow "values" as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71414803/cannot-borrow-values-as-immutable-because-it-is-also-borrowed-as-mutable) The problem is fundamentally the same -- a function that takes a mutable reference and returns an immutable reference causes the mutable borrow to exist as long as the immutable reference returned continues to exist, which is why you can't invoke `read_slice` a second time until you drop the reference it returns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [duplicate I linked as a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71414803/cannot-borrow-values-as-immutable-because-it-is-also-borrowed-as-mutable) addresses *why* you get this error.  (tl;dr: Rust doesn't downgrade borrows; a function borrowing a value mutably and returning an immutable reference with the same lifetime causes the mutable borrow to exist as long as the returned reference does.)

How might we solve the problem in this case?

When I think "cursor" I don't think "something that owns data and allows reading that data out," I think "something that reads out data owned by something else."  It turns out that model can solve this problem by having something else to tie the lifetime of the returned reference to.

If we make `Cursor` *borrow* the data instead of owning it, we can denote that the returned reference is bound to the lifetime of that data instead of the mutable borrow of `self`:

```
struct Cursor<'a> {
    offset: usize,
    data: &'a [u8],
}
impl<'a> Cursor<'a> {
    fn read_slice(&mut self, n: usize) -> &'a [u8] {
        let data = &self.data[self.offset..self.offset + n];
        self.offset += n;
        data
    }
}
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=cbdf0e25f7de5cc73b0c9ca0d554e995))

If you want `Cursor` to own the data then interior mutability (e.g. `offset: Cell<usize>`) may be your only option:

```
struct Cursor {
    offset: Cell<usize>,
    data: [u8; 4],
}
impl Cursor {
    fn read_slice(&self, n: usize) -> &[u8] {
        let offset = self.offset.get();

        let data = &self.data[offset..offset + n];
        self.offset.set(offset + n);
        data
    }
}
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a3219909f5c133d1c4fd1f436af90680))

Comment: Is there any workaround?, If `Cursor` own the data ?

Comment: @Stone Interior mutability of `offset` via a `Cell`.

Comment: Is this only solution? `Cell` ?

Comment: @Stone That or `RefCell` but that's overkill here since you don't need references. I've added an example using a cell; note that `read_slice` takes `&self` instead of `&mut self` in this case.

Comment: Actually, `Cursor` implementation is something look like this, `impl<T: AsRef<[u8]>> Cursor<T> { ... }` Where the `data` is owned by `cursor`, and it need excursive reference in-order to increase the `offset` without Interior mutability...

Comment: @Stone You don't really have other options here. If you accept `&mut self` and return a reference without something else to tie the lifetime of that reference to, the returned reference will extend the mutable borrow. This is the way Rust works.

Comment: So in summary you can either have something else own the data, or you can give interior mutability to the offset through `Cell`. I can't think of another way to accomplish what you are asking for.

Comment: If that is the only solution (Interior mutability) or borrowing `data`, Then it answer ✅ my question... Though still looking for alternative (If there is any), Thanks for your time...